# Using LINQ to combine the results of 2 queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have 2 entities `Book` and `Borrow`, if I fetch **1.** a list of `Book` entities in one query then fetch **2.** a list of `Borrow` entities in another, how can I use LINQ to build a list like this?

List of books:

```
Book.Borrows
Book.Borrows
Book.Borrows
Book.Borrows
```

So each `Book` has a list of it's borrows mapped to it from the 2nd query that fetches the `Borrow` list.

Navigation properties:

Class `Borrow`:

```
public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
```

Class `Book`:

```
public virtual List<Borrow> Borrows { get; set; }
```

Comment: Use `Include` to eager load `Borrows` for each `Book` [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: Is that a sub-query for each Book or does EF do some processing to get all the data from 2 tables in the background?

Answer (score 1):

No need to make 2 queries. You can just do that in a single one. You can refer both in a single query. That's the use of having navigation properties in the first place. So you can easily traverse the related objects too.

```
context.Books
    .Include("Borrows")  // If you have lazy loading
    .Where(..some condition...)
    .Select(b => new BookModel
    {
       BookName = b.Name,
       Borrows = b.Borrows.Select(...select properties...).ToList()
    }
```

Comment: You mean `.Include("Borrows")`?

Comment: Does entity framework create 2 queries in the background to get the row from the 2 entities?

Comment: @matt no it won't. It will do a join between the tables. You can check that using profiler what query gets fired

Comment: The `Include` is redundant. It doesn't have any effect because of the projection (`new`). Also, it's the opposite of lazy loading, the comment is erratic.

Comment: @GertArnold I believe it's not. As the comment states, if the lazy loading is enabled and we don't have `Include` there, it will actually fire 2 queries to the database. With Includes, it will join the tables and try to get the related data in a single query.

Comment: I suggest you try. The idea of an expression tree is that it's translated into SQL as one statement.

Comment: How do I use the Borrows in the where condition, where(Borrow.BookId == Book.Id)

Comment: @matt in the same way its used in the select. Where(b=> b.Borrows...

Comment: @GertArnold sure. I will give that a try. Better sure than in doubt.

Comment: I'm using the Include("Borrows") https://pastebin.com/7dN32Cra, now I'm getting error: System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'TestAPI.Database.Book' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'